# VBA code to go to previous page

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a VBA code to go to previous sheet. A code with I will be able to add a button to every sheet and by pushing it I will go back to the last (previous) sheet from which I got to the present sheet.

Example: I go to sheet1 from sheet7. Now in sheet1 there is back button through which i can go back to sheet 7. Something "similar" to the "BACK" button in Internet Explorer.
Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Try recording a macro while pressing Ctrl+Page Up and Ctrl+Page Down and see if that gives you any ideas.  It won't solve your second question, but it'll get you going the right direction for your first.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a regulare code module (Module1 in my case):

```
Public PreviousSheetNum As Integer

Sub GoBack()
  Worksheets(PreviousSheetNum).Activate
End Sub
```

And in the ThisWorkbook module, put this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
  Module1.PreviousSheetNum = Sh.Index
End Sub
```

So basically whenever the user changes sheet, the index of the previously selected sheet is remebered, and you can go back to that sheet any time you wish.

Be warned though that changing sheet order or deleting sheets might produce unexpected behaviour. You can change from remembering the sheet index to remembering it's name, but it has some possible issues too.

Hope this helps.